# How to proxy a web service using camel?

Tags: web-services, cxf, apache-camel

I have a web service implemented using spring, cxf and jax ws implementation. My service exposes 10 operations and some operations returns more than 200 fields. Now I want to proxy my web service using camel. Means I want to provide different WSDLs to different clients with only required operations and required fields. One of our client wants a particular operation of 10 operations with only some fields of 200 fields exposed from that operation of that web service. How can I achieve this through camel?

Answer (score 1):

see http://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried camel proxy example provided by apache camel and able to run it. I installed camel as a bundle with camel context defined. But i am unsuccessful when i try to use process and try to get response from exchange object. In Camel context i defined from as cxf:endpoint created in same context file, and defined "to" to preexisting services. After "to" i have another "to" which is referring to process bean which is implementing Process interface.I am not able to get response back and when i try to debug and see exchange object,I could not see any trace of response.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you deploy your Camel instance, there might be pros and cons with CXF.

If you bundle your camel within a spring enabled web application, then you might also want to check out Spring-WS in Camel. It's a bit more light weight than CXF, but a bit limited. It can, although suite your needs. http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html

Spring-WS does not really bind to a specific WSDL, but rather specific operations. 
Like this:

from("spring-ws:rootqname:{http://example.com/}GetFoo?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping").bean(prepareProxy)
.to("spring-ws:http://foo.com/bar").bean(prepareAnswer);

Dependent on how complex the transformation for the answer you need, you can do it in Java or XSLT or by some other scripting language of choice. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried camel proxy example provided by apache camel and able to run it. I am installing camel as a bundle with camel context defined. But i am unsuccessful when i try to use process and try to get response from exchange object.